# Nginx logs for multiple timezones

Tags: nginx, timezone

In my nginx config, I have several servers block. Each block has its own access/error log in different path.

```
server {
    server_name 1
    access_log /path1/access_log  <-- use UTC
}

server {
    server_name 2
    access_log /path2/access_log  <-- use Asia/Singapore
}
```

Is it possible to use different timezone settings for these two logs?

The intention of this is I have multiple other sources of data that I need to align with access log

Answer (score 0):

The [`access_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) directive takes an optional log_format directive, that governs the information recorded in that specific log file.

The default format is `combined` but AFAIK the [`log_format`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) directive allows you to define your own with a different timestamp.

It might be easier to do some post processing though in the system where you will correlating the different datasources though.